# Strange issue with resources in .NET 2

Tags: c#, resources, .net-2.0

In VS 2010 SP 1 I've created WinForms application for .Net Framework 2. And I try to get icon from resources and assign it to form icon:

```
this.Icon = global::tester.Properties.Resources.icon_gray;
```

Icon resource icon_gray.ico was added from VS designer to Resources.resx in my developer PC Windows 7 x86 with .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, and .NET 4.

But got the below error in `Windows XP SP 3 with only .NET Framework 2 SP 2`

**Error**:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Параметр задан неверно
   at System.Drawing.Icon.Initialize(Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._SerializationInvoke(Object target, SignatureStruct& declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.SerializationInvoke(Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.DeserializeObject(Int32 typeIndex)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObject(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
   at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean isString)
   at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo culture, Boolean wrapUnmanagedMemStream)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at tester.Properties.Resources.get_icon_gray()
   at tester.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

How to fix this? 
**Edit:**
With png:

```
pictureBox1.Image = global::tester.Properties.Resources.icon_gray1;
```

everything is fine

Comment: Please translate the Russian message

Comment: What resolution is your icon? "The parameter is incorrect" error kind of points to the problem that wrong parameters are passed into `System.Drawing.Icon.Initialize` and the icon cannot be loaded/resolved. I don't know the real answer but the problem very well might be different *.ico files handling in XP and post-XP Windows systems. Try reproducing the same issue with *.png file. If it works, then the problem is the ICO handling indeed. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29#History) out for details.

Comment: @Migol: http://translate.google.com/#ru/en/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: Icon have 32x32 resolution. On my Developer PC it's all good

Comment: As you mentioned in question, the problem only happens on Windows XP. I can only speculate because I don't have an XP machine to check this behavior. However, it would be interesting to know if the problem can be reproduced with PNG files.

Comment: @Migol..Did you mean ..Please translate TO Russian message..;)

Comment: Load up a virtual machine with Windows XP and install the current version of .NET Framework 2 with all updates.  Then debug the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have encountered this problem, make sure you check the icon in the project properties window and also, the icon property in all of you forms. They all have to be 32x32 in order to work in Windows XP.